# Технология реализации прогресс бара на стороне клиента и сервера

Tags: php, html, css, css3

Как мы все знаем php скрипт выполняется на стороне сервера и после его отработки отдается клиенту. Можно в настройках сервера указать - выводить информацию клиенту по мере вывода информации, но это неприемлемая настройка. Также я узнал что с помощью веб сокетов можно устанавливать прямое соединение клиент-сервер и, следовательно видеть результат работы программы, вот только непонятно вывод будет по мере поступления информации или после отработки всего скрипта на стороне сервера. Также непонятно как рисовать прогресс бар на стороне клиента. Самый простой это div с бэкграундом и как на лету дописывать css. Может использовать ajax и долбить базу данных каждую секунду. Поясните как это реализуется. Или может необходимо изучить документацию по HTTP и в заголовке передавать какую то информацию. В общем не понимаю откуда начинать копать.

Comment: я не понимаю как эти запросы ajax мне могут помочь? во первых мне необходимо обращаться к одному скрипту php, узнавать его готовность и оповещать об этом клиента, а ajax может отдать ответ только тогда когда сервер выполнил работу скрипта. А во вторых даже если я захочу через секунду узнать как изменилось состояние выполнения php скрипта, ajax пойдет и запустит новый php скрипт а мне этого совсем не надо

Comment: можно серверную часть писать на js, используя Node.js + реактивный фреймворк для динамического изменения контента на фронте, тогда вообще нет никаких проблем в прогресс-барах и тому подобных вещах

Comment: Основной вопрос все таки не ясен - как показать клиенту через прогресс бар о % выполнении php скрипта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть прогресс бары(все они выполняются на стороне клиента), которые работают при загрузке файла на сервер и обратно в случае когда когда мы отсылаем файл, либо принимаем, такие прогресс бары вы можете увидеть в CMS WordPress их принцип - обращение к ресурсам браузера.

Мой же прогресс бар, как и у многих выполняет какие-то действия на сервере исходя из данных, полученных от клиента, любо по команде от пользователя запускает долгий процесс - предположим парсинг 2 000 000 страниц. Если бы это все делалось за 1 проход, то для этого пришлось бы выделить на работу скрипта несколько недель и как правило бы закончилось ошибкой. Поскольку у нас может быть обычный хостинг со стандартными настройками сервера, в которые мы лазить не можем, нам придется реализовать код с прерываниями, и, поскольку скрипт может выполняться неделями, сессии нам не подойдут, поскольку нет возможности держать окно браузера открытым на протяжении нескольких недель. Случай когда одно и то же приложение запущено на разных компьютерах не рассматривается, поскольку нашему приложению необходимы все ресурсы сервера.

На стороне клиента мы должны по кнопке запускать рекурсивный спагетти код, использовав исключительно ajax.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Процесс обновления базы</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="v/css/style.css">
 <script src="v/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <main class="main">
  <div class="container">
   <div id="preloader">
    <div id="progress"></div>
    <div id="progress_info"><span class="procent">0</span>% Примерно осталось <span class="time">...</span></div>
   </div>
   <div id="go">Запуск!</div>
  </div>
 </main>
</body>
</html>
<script>
 var go=true,goods_count=0,size=0,i=10,start=+new Date(),end_start=+new Date(),mid=0;
 $.post('c/post.php',{'act':'distance_count'},function(reply){i=reply;console.log(reply);});
 function load(cur_i){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "distance.php",
    data: {'i':i},
    success: function(reply){
   console.log(reply);
    i++;
    $('.procent').text(Math.floor(i/size*100));
    $('#progress').css({'width':Math.floor(i/size*100)+'%'});
   if(!mid) mid=+new Date()-start;
   else mid=(mid*i+new Date()-start)/(i+1);
    //end_start=(+new Date()-start)*(size-i)/1000;
    end_start=+mid*(size-i)/1000;
   
   
    if(end_start<60) $('.time').text(Math.floor(end_start)+' c');
    else if(end_start/60<60){
    $('.time').text(Math.floor(end_start/60)+' мин.'+Math.floor(end_start%60)+' c');
   } 
    else if(end_start/60/60<24) {
    $('.time').text(Math.floor(end_start/60/60)+' часов'+Math.floor(end_start%60)+' мин.');
   }
   else  {
    $('.time').text(Math.floor(end_start/60/60/24)+' дней'+Math.floor(end_start/60/60%24)+' часов');
   }
    start=+new Date();
    if(i<size)load(i);
    else $('#progress_info').html('выполнено');
    },
    error: function(){
     start=+new Date();
     load(i);
    }
  });
 }
 $('#go').click(function(){
  if(go){
   go=false;
   $('#progress_info').fadeIn();
   $.post('c/post.php',{'act':'places_count'},function(reply){
    goods_count=+reply;
    size=goods_count*10;
    //size=5;
    start=+new Date();
    load(i);
   });
  }
  
 });
</script>
```

Здесь указан частный пример, но этот принцип я использовал и в других задачах. Самое основное что здесь необходимо увидеть это во первых

```js
var go=true,goods_count=0,size=0,i=10,start=+new Date(),end_start=+new Date(),mid=0;
 $.post('c/post.php',{'act':'distance_count'},function(reply){i=reply;console.log(reply);});
```

Здесь мы узнаем от сервера сколько мы уже выполнили проходов и записываем в переменную i, По нажатию на кнопку запуска парсера чего угодно, мы должны узнать а сколько всего проходов нам делать вот собственно это и делает код

```js
$('#go').click(function(){
  if(go){
   go=false;
   $('#progress_info').fadeIn();
   $.post('c/post.php',{'act':'places_count'},function(reply){
    goods_count=+reply;
    size=goods_count*10;
    //size=5;
    start=+new Date();
    load(i);
   });
  }
  
 });
```

Мы защитили себя от повторного нажатия на запуск, переведя go=false; Подсветили панель о рассчете оставшегося времени $('#progress_info').fadeIn();
Запросили у сервера из файла c/post.php количество проходов и записали это в переменную size=goods_count*10; В вашем случае это будет скорее всего size=goods_count;

Обозначаем время загрузки start=+new Date(); - это нам поможет высчитать временной интервал отработки скрипта (я выбрал экспериментально - об этом процессе указывает закоменченная строка //size=5; что мне достаточно выполнение скрипта в длительностью 25-45 секунд, предположим 450 товаров за одно обращение к серверу) и запускаем нашу рекурсивную функцию load(i); которой мы передаем единственный параметр - на каком этапе мы находимся. В задачу этой функции будет входить:

1. Передать на сервер текущее состояние (например 3000) Поймав число 3000, сервер поймет, что 3000 раз уже был выполнен цикл и что не стоит начинать сначала, а сразу перейти к 3000, 3001 , 3002 ...
2. Должен получить ответ от сервера, неважно какой с ошибкой или без
3. Действовать по разному если ответ успешный и если ответ неудачный

```js
function load(cur_i){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "distance.php",
    data: {'i':i},
    success: function(reply){
      i++;
            start=+new Date();
      if(i<size)load(i);
      else $('#progress_info').html('выполнено');
    },
    error: function(){
     start=+new Date();
     load(i);
    }
  });
 }
```

в случае успеха мы добавляем к счетчику единицу, проверяем достигли ли мы цели, если нет - идем к ней
если ошибка на сервере - то запускаем повторно

я как то сперва попытался это реализовать следующим образом

```js
for(var i=0;i<size;i++){
  $.post('c/do.php',{'i':i},function(reply){
    //какая то информация для прогресс бара
  });
}
```

но получил ужас - у меня прогресс бар скакал. Оказывается ява скрипт выстрелил весь цикл за секунду а потом мне приходили ответы от запыхавшегося сервера, хорошо что я тогда поставил ограничение для size

а что  касается внешнего оформления прогресс бара - то у каждого он может быть своим. Промежуточные итоги вам лучше хранить в базе данных, в крайнем случае в файле. Будут вопросы - пишите.

Comment: а что касается кода на сервере то он был одинаковым, изменялись лишь запросы к базе данных в зависимости от параметра i, а сам код выполнял запись в базу. Поскольку код выполнял запись в базу, то запуская скажем утром парсер $.post('c/post.php',{'act':'distance_count'},function(reply){i=reply;console.log(reply);}); обращаясь к базе выдавал обновленные данные.

Answer (score 2):

Вот Вам простой прогрессбар сделанный на коленке

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var setProgress = function(ABar, AVal) {
    var width = ABar.width();
    var margin = width - width * AVal / 100;
    $('.progress', ABar).css({'margin-right': margin});
    $('.val', ABar).text(AVal);
  };

  var percent = 0;
  setProgress($('#bar'), percent);

  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    percent++;
    setProgress($('#bar'), percent);
    if (percent >= 100)
      clearInterval(interval);
    }, 100
  );
});
```

```css
#bar {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 150px;
}
.progress {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bar">
  <div class="progress">
    <span class="val">0</span>%
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: отличная реализация! - теперь осталось разобраться с тем что данные у нас идут с сервера, а не тикают каждые 100 милисекунд и как понять сервер выполнил 50% PHP скрипта например. Например парсер работает 15 мин, может конечно и меньше не в этом соль. Как правило я слышал что для этой реализации необходимо использовать NodeJS и что для реализации прогрессбара на стороне клиента php лучше не использовать. Основной вопрос все таки не ясен - как показать клиенту через прогресс бар о % выполнении php скрипта. Я тут читал о создании демона и множестве процессов параллельных,  о многопоточных реализ

Comment: тыкните меня как котенка в документацию, я не знаю откуда копать

Comment: Может вам поможет http://expange.ru/e/%D0%A3%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0_(PHP) (увеличение времени работы php скрипта). + еще помню была команда по выводу html  на клиент прямо во время выполнения скрипта но я ее не вспомню(если echo не смогет можно попробовать print но учтите что print без особого буфера и он будет выводится всегда первее любого echo)

Comment: Но все это не очень хорошая идея. Закачка файлов можно воспользоватся html фитчами(они хорошо связываются с пхп и вы получите переменные). А так js в клиентском деле.